# Stracture an xml in to a one long line

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xml that i want to stracture in to a one ling line.

When I tried to replace "\n" in each line with nothing in notepad++ it failed.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check whether your XML serializer can be configured in order to produce the required output.

If not feasible, Notepad++ provides the XMLTools plugin which features a "Linarize XML" option.